# Function that alphabetically displays names of individuals from a text file

Tags: c, string, file-io

Text file content example:

> He is called Andrew. Andrew loves Martha.
>
> They both will marry with Jonathan.

Console expected output:

> Andrew, Jonathan, Martha

I did open and read the file successfully, but I am not entirely sure how to go on. I was thinking about parsing the text file into an array, but **I am not sure how to get the elements of an array which meet two conditions simultaneously: they are words that start with a capital letter and are not at the beginning of any sentence.**

```
//Reading part which works good
int ReadFile(FILE* file) {
    char c;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
//but how do I go on to accomplish what I explained above
```

Some help regarding this problem would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: " I am not entirely sure how to go on" is too broad.  What specifically is your uncertainly?  Starting point: research `isupper()`.

Comment: @chux My uncertainty is how do I get the console expected output from the exemplified file content shown above . Thanks, now I am taking a look at ```isupper()```.

Comment: Your code reads single characters, but words are made up of multiple characters (in general; I realize there's a word or two with single letters in them).  So, step 1 is "read words" and "save words in an array" or thereabouts.  Once you can read words, you can start studying them.  What makes 'Andrew', 'Martha' and 'Jonathan' into names and 'He' and 'They' not?  If there was a new name at the start of a sentence ('Caroline loved them all.'), how does that complicate things?  Can you have an exhaustive list of names?  Can you create a list of non-names?

Comment: Incidentally, there are bugs in your code. You need `int c;` to be safe. The `getc()` and `getchar()` functions return an `int` and not a `char`; they return any possible `char` value plus an extra value, `EOF` — and you can't fit all those into a single `char`. Also, since the function only returns 0 and never any other value, it would be better if it returned `void` (nothing) so that callers don't have to check what's returned. And in general the function that calls `fopen()` should call `fclose()` – this function does not call `fopen()`, so it probably shouldn't call `fclose()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hey, thanks for your input! If you read my question, you can see my issue, "I am not sure how to get the elements of an array which meet two conditions simultaneously: they are words that start with a capital letter and are not at the beginning of any sentence". I am not sure how to put it under the form of a code.
Also, thank you for telling me about the bugs, I corrected them right away. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Start with "what's a word" and "what's the start of a sentence".  How can you identify either of those.  As I said, your code doesn't work with words — it works with characters, and while Jonathan, Andrew and Martha are characters in the text, their names are more than a single character long.  So, that's a start — you need to read words, and make an appropriate choice about punctuation (but what about O'Reilly?).  What rule(s) are you going to apply if the first word isn't capitalized?  And you're going to need to save words, and search for words, and print words.  Work on that, too.

Comment: If you problem is with checking two conditions which both are met, then please demosntrate how you check each of the two conditions on its own. If then really checking both is your only problem, then use `&&`, the logical AND operator.